# how to recognise paragraphs and table at word document

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

There has a big word document, doc content mix with paragraphs and tables. how to auto recogise paragraphs and tables, and then I want to parse it to JSON.

Below is word example:
[image: Word Document Example]
I found the Range object has start and end property, its looks like I can used to identifier table end.

Did there has other solution?

Comment: You need to read up on  other properties and methods of the Range Property. e.g. Paragraphs, Tables and the useful methods .Information and .Next

Comment: You should **not** try to use the `Start` and `End` properties of the `Range` object to identify anything - they're not reliable for this. You may want to investigate leveraging the Word Open XML file format, possibly using the Open XML SDK. But as it is, this question is too broad as well as unclear.

Comment: @CindyMeister Did there has any Open XML SKD documents or demos. The SDK parse Word to a complicate xml, I don't know how to read a complete paragraphs or tables easly.